# Filter NSMutableArray Containing A List of Messages

Tags: ios, uitableview, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

I am trying to filter and sort an NSMutableArray containing a list of Chat Messages. I am trying to get the Last Message of a conversation between 2 users. For example if user1 has 2 different conversations with 2 separate users, I want to get the last message of each of those conversations. I am using Parse.com as backend and this how I saved & retrieved the messages.

**Saving the Messages**

```
PFUser *user = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"displayName"];
PFObject *newMessage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Messages"];
[newMessage setObject:messageStr forKey:@"body"];
[newMessage setObject:self.mySelectedUser forKey:@"toUser"];
[newMessage setObject:user forKey:@"fromUser"];
[newMessage saveInBackground];
myMessageField.text = @"";
[self getTheNewMessages];
[self.myTView reloadData];
```

**Retrieving The Messages**

```
-(void)GetmyNewMessages

{
PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];
[query1 whereKey:@"toUser"  equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"displayName"]];
 [query1 whereKeyExists:@"date"];

PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];
[query2 whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"displayName"]];
[query2 whereKeyExists:@"date"];

 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:query1, query2, nil]];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {


             NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d chats.", objects.count);
            [premessagesList removeAllObjects];
            [premessagesList addObject:objects];
     } else {
            //Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);


        }


    }];
```

}

**NSLog of the NSMutableArray (premessageList)**

```
   ( "<Messages:aS8tVIlsHc:(null)> {\n   
     body = hi;\n  fromUser = cnn;\n    toUser =FNC;\n    
     date = \"2012-09-19 02:40:29 +0000\";\n}",

    "<Messages:CPCa6VBmf7:(null)> {\n  
body = hello;\n  fromUser = FNC;\n    toUser =cnn;\n   
 date = \"2012-09-20 05:06:05 +0000\";\n}",


    "<Messages:Jz1cILt18Y:(null)> {\n   

     body = whatsgood;\n  fromUser = sleepy;\n    toUser =cnn;\n

  date =\"2012-09-20 05:06:05 +0000\";\n}",

    "<Messages:lXretmE1uK:(null)> {\n   
     body = lol;\n  fromUser = cnn;\n    toUser =sleepy;\n

 date =\"2012-09-20 05:13:16 +0000\";\n}",
```

I tried to use  NSSortDescriptor and NSPredicate but I got an empty tableview.

Answer (score 0):

In this type of problem, I would use some variables and fast iteration to slog through the info and get what you need:

```
id lastChat = ni;
... temps 

for(OneChat in allChats) {
  do tests and set variables
}

Now I know the last chat.
```

PS: I decided not to post this, but when I saw after a long time no one had responded felt it was better than nothing. This is how I would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could limit the results and sort through the `PFQuery` itself like this:

```
[query1 orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
query1.limit = 1;
[query2 orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
query2.limit = 1;
```